# Angular - Error: Cannot find control with name:

Tags: angular, typescript

Antes de nada, decir que he estado probando las soluciones propuestas para casos similares al mío sin resultado. No sé si se trata de que la solución es diferente o es que no sé aplicarlo correctamente.

Dicho esto, me explico:

Tengo el siguiente componente (un formulario de registro):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  FormBuilder,
  Validators,
  NgForm,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css'],
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  angForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private dataService: ApiService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
  
    this.angForm = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.email]],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      //mobile: ['', Validators.required],
      hentrada_con: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.max(23)]],
      minentrada_con: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.max(59)]],
      hsalida_con: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.max(23)]],
      minsalida_con: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.max(59)]]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  postdata(angForm1: any) {
    this.dataService
      .userregistration(
        angForm1.value.name,
        angForm1.value.email,
        angForm1.value.password,
        angForm1.value.hentrada_con,
        angForm1.value.minentrada_con,
        angForm1.value.hsalida_con,
        angForm1.value.minsalida_con
      )
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
        },

        (error) => {}
      );
  }

  get email() {
    return this.angForm.get('email');
  }
  get password() {
    return this.angForm.get('password');
  }
  get name() {
    return this.angForm.get('name');
  }
  get hentrada_con(){
    return this.angForm.get('hentrada_con');
  }
  get minentrada_con(){
    return this.angForm.get('minentrada_con');
  }
  get hsalida_con(){
    return this.angForm.get('hsalida_con');
  }
  get minsalida_con(){
    return this.angForm.get('minsalida_con');
  }

}
```

Aquí la función userregistration en api.service.ts

```
public userregistration(
    name: string,
    email: string,
    pwd: string,
    hen_con: number,
    minen_con: number,
    hsal_con: number,
    minsal_con: number
  ) {
    return this.httpClient
      .post<any>(this.baseUrl + '/register.php', {
        name,
        email,
        pwd,
        hen_con,
        minen_con,
        hsal_con,
        minsal_con,
      })
      .pipe(
        map((Users) => {
          return Users;
        })
      );
  }
```

Con la siguiente vista:

```
<h2 class="text-center">Registro</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <form [formGroup]="angForm" (ngSubmit)="postdata(angForm)" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name" autocomplete="off"
                        class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" formControlName="email" autocomplete="off"
                        class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Password">Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="password" name="Password" formControlName="password" autocomplete="off"
                        class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Contraseña">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="hen_con">Hora de entrada</label>
                    <input type="number" name="hen_con" formControlName="hen_con" autocomplete="off"
                        class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="hora">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" name="minen_con" formControlName="minen_con" autocomplete="off"
                        class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="minutos">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="hsal_con">Hora de salida</label>
                    <input type="number" name="hsal_con" formControlName="hsal_con" autocomplete="off"
                        class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="hora">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" name="minsal_con" formControlName="minsal_con" autocomplete="off"
                        class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="minutos">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Registrar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

El problema es que a la hora de enviar el formulario, me dan error los últimos imputs (hen_con, minen_con, hsal_con, minsal_con). Aquí dejo un fragmento del error del navegador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además, los parámetros introducidos en esos imputs no se envían

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aparece esto en la sección Salida del navegador

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>AquíaparecelaurldeldocumentoPHPalqueseestállamando:15:</small><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'INSERT INTO empleados(name,password,email,hentrada_con,minentrada_con,hsalida_con,minsalida_con) VALUES (&#39;maria&#39;,&#39;maria&#39;,&#39;maria@maria.com&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;&#39;)'</font> <i>(length=151)</i>
</pre>
```

*Nota: tras la etiqueta small he quitado la dirección por privacidad y seguridad

Lo más raro, y es lo que no entiendo por las soluciones que se proponen para este tipo de error, es que ni funciona añadiéndole un formGroupName, ni los campos name, password y email dan error. De hecho, esos 3 campos funcionan correctamente (he podido añadir filas a la tabla de la bd) y ha sido al ampliar el formulario cuando ha surgido el problema

Gracias por adelantado.

ACTUALIZACION: Gracias a @Lobos, ya he conseguido que el formulario se almacene en la bd. He sustituido en el html los formGroupName para que concuerden con los del angForm.

Comment: `formControlName="hen_con"` ese control no existe en `angForm`.

Comment: Antes de nada, gracias, porque has dado con la clave. Ahora el formulario sí se graba en la bd. Sin embargo, sale un error JSON en la consola del navegador, parecido al que indicaba en la pregunta. Lo he añadido

Comment: Nada. Corregido. Había un var_dump que no había borrado